# C++ basic multithreading troubleshooting

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates

Whenever I try to compile this program, I get the error: "error C2661: 'std::thread::thread' : no overloaded function takes 7 arguments". I get this when I try to make the threads with

```
genparts<T>
```

or just

```
genparts.
```

I'm trying to familiarize myself with threads at the moment, for what it's worth.

I know that I shouldn't have a function with so many parameters passed in, and that it would be better to pass in a struct with this information-- this is something I'll fix once I've got everything up and running.

```
template <typename T>
void genparts(unsigned int target, unsigned int &total, unsigned int low, unsigned int high, map<unsigned int, unsigned int> container, T gen){
return;}
```

And a calling function:

```
void genpart(unsigned int target, map<unsigned int, unsigned int> &container, T& gen){
unsigned int total[2];
map<unsigned int, unsigned int> results[2];
do{
    total[0]=0;
    total[1]=0;
    thread t1(genparts<T>, target, total[0], 1, target/2, results[0], gen);
    thread t2(genparts<T>, target, total[1], 1+(target/2), target, results[1], gen);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}while(total[0]+total[1] != target);
}
```

I very much appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: I will assume you need thread<genparts<T>> as classes does not automatically guess the template types by parameters. Please correct if I am not correct.

Comment: Doesn't work-- I'm getting syntax errors: "syntax error : missing ';' before '<'"

Comment: Ah! Fixed it! It was poor templating on my part that I had actually fixed (kind-of) in my post, but not my code, by accident. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of details are wrong... like the number of arguments you're passing along (where did the container go?), and you're making copies of the map all the time. But most importantly, arguments that need to be passed by reference to the thread function need to be wrapped in `std::ref`. Putting it all together, here's a version that "works":

```
#include <map>
#include <thread>

template <typename T>
void genparts(unsigned int target, unsigned int &total,
              unsigned int low, unsigned int high,
              std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int>& container, T& gen)
{ /* ... */   }

template <typename T>
void genpart(unsigned int target,
             std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> &container, T& gen)
{
  unsigned int total[2];
  std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> results[2];
  do
  {
    total[0] = 0;
    total[1] = 0;
    std::thread t1(genparts<T>, target, std::ref(total[0]), 1,
                   target / 2, std::ref(container), std::ref(gen));
    std::thread t2(genparts<T>, target, std::ref(total[1]), 1 + (target / 2),
                   target, std::ref(container), std::ref(gen));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
  } while (total[0] + total[1] != target);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know you had to use std::ref() in place of "&" when making threads, not even considering my careless mistakes. I think I should go around and get a real C++11 or C++14 book to learn threads, looking around online allows me to make so many careless errors. Thank you so much!